# How to Hide Modal Popup if Variable = True

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following code that creates a modal popup when a user clicks a textbox control:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel2" CancelControlID="lblClose2" TargetControlID="txtEmail"

    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">

</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...<span style="float:right; margin:-5px 10px 0 0"><asp:Label ID="lblClose2" Text="X" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" style="margin-right:10px;cursor:pointer" ></asp:Label></span><br /><br />

</asp:Panel>
```

I would like to hide/ disable that code if the following variable is equal to `true`:

```
bool bSHOW_WEBSITE_EXIST_USERS = Sql.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Application["CONFIG.SHOW_WEBSITE_EXIST_USERS"]);
```

Is it possible to do this programmatically within my codebehind script or must I do this inline?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show and hide it from codebehind, then you can use `ModalPopupName.Show()` and `ModalPopupName.Hide()`
There is a sample that I found in this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1365393.aspx) that shows and hides a modal popup based on a condition. It might help you.

Comment: This seems to be a little more complex than I thought.  Is there no way to simply do it from the code behind by saying `if (bSHOW_WEBSITE_EXIST_USERS) { // do something }`?

Comment: That works; however, it shows it as soon as the page is loaded, but I only want it to show if `bSHOW_WEBSITE_EXIST_USERS = true` and if the user clicks on the textbox control.  Is this possible?  The code I have now is just `if (bSHOW_WEBSITE_EXIST_USERS)
            {
                ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
            }`

Comment: I ended up using `ModalPopupExtender2.Enabled = true;` and `ModalPopupExtender2.Enabled = false;`.